# Gradle repositories conflict forces me to use repository in two places

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, dependency-management, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Gradle [multi-project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) build. Which has a project `myApplication` that uses a library `utils`.
The library requires a JasperReports dependency with a custom repository. There is a particular Jasper dependency that produces an error when retrieved from `mavenCentral()`.

If I build `utils` by itself, it works. Because it fetches the problem jar from the custom repo.
However, if I build `myApplication` it produces the maven repository error, because it tries to solve the dependency using its `mavenCentral()` repo.

`myApplication/build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("application")
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
application {
    mainClass.set("com.myapp.SomeMainClass")
}
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":utils"))
}
```

`utils/build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id ("java-library")
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/")
        isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
    mavenCentral()
} 
dependencies {
    implementation("net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.18.1")
}
```

If I include the custom repository in `myApplication/build.gradle.kts` the project builds ok, but I think adding the custom repo seems like a bad practice, and I think [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html) discourages it.
I think this is actually using a *direct dependency* in myApplication instead of fixing a *transitive dependency*. But of that I'm not so sure, and completely lost on how to solve it. I'm really struggling reading the documentation.

**Is there a way for me to have Gradle just compile `:utils` first, and then have `:myAplication` use the dependency *"as is"*?**

Comment: I'd recommend setting up a [centralized repository declaration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration) in the root `settings.gradle.kts` and removing any repository declaration from all `build.gradle.kts`s, then the repositories will be standardised for all subprojects

Comment: Yes... I did that in `buildSrc/settings.gradle.kts` at some point, have both repositories within a common plugin, but still feels like a bad practice, we are basically declaring a potentially unsafe HTTP repository for all of my projects. Still think there has to be a way to tell Gradle: "for this particular project" compile and prevent library overriding... just not sure how

Comment: Ah okay, so I think changing `implementation(<jasper>)` to `api(<jasper>)` in `utils/build.gradle.kts` is what you want.

Comment: If you're concerned about security then you can [add a filter to the insecure repo](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-content-filtering) so it will only be allowed to provide the Jasper dependency. Or just download the jar, commit it to your repo, and [define a directory as a repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:flat_dir_resolver) - no need for insecure repositories.

Comment: Oh, actually this looks like what you want: [Declaring content exclusively found in one repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#declaring_content_exclusively_found_in_one_repository)